# MongoDB find document in collection based on 2 IDs PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I was wondering how to find document in collection based on UIDa and UIDb which could be also vice versa.

So for example I want to get all documents where
value UIDa = inputA and UIDb = inputB
or value UIDa = inputB and UIDb = inputA

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5572f65dc89782b9398b4fc0"), 
    "sender" : "senderID", 
    "recipient" : "recipientID", 
    "message" : "messagehere", 
    "time" : "1433092679", 
    "state" : "1" 
}
```

I have this query but it doesn't work because some of the documents are missing.

```
$query = $db->collection->find(array(
    '$or' => array(
         array(
             'recipient' => $uid,
             'sender' => $fuid, 
             'state' => '1', 
             'time' => array(
                 '$lt' => $last_update
              )
          ),
          array(
              'recipient' => $fuid, 
              'sender' => $uid, 
              'state' => '1', 
              'time' => array(
                  '$lt' => $last_update
              )
          )
      )
    )
)->limit(20);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an example of a document it "falters on"?

Comment: @Philipp
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5572f65dc89782b9398b4fc0"), "sender" : "senderID", "recepient" : "recepientID", "message" : "messagehere", "time" : "1433092679", "state" : "1" }

all of the documents are pretty same just different values of course but is seems like random problem. It pulls some documents correctly but some of them not. They're just missing.

Comment: In relational db I would have to use 2 queries but I hope that it's possible with one query in Mongo.

Comment: @Philipp thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think what you are looking for the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

```
$query = $db->collection->find(array(
             'recepient' => array('$in' => array($uid, $fuid)),
             'sender' => array('$in' => array($uid, $fuid)),
             'state' => '1', 
             'time' => array('$lt' => $last_update)
          )
)->limit(20);
```

Comment: thank your very much for your help, this is exactly what I wanted everything works now.

it loads data from both situations as I wanted but some of the data were still missing and I found out that the problem was data type. Timestamp in time field was saved as integer but I needed it as string.